# systax error: missing operan after "%" operator

Tags: vb.net

Tengo el siguiente error en el siguiente código, estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas como de practica para aprender visual basic pero el video que estoy viendo utiliza el código y no le sale el mismo error que a mí, me gustaría saber cual es mi equivocación.

```
dv.RowFilter = Cbocampo.Text & "like'" & Txtbuscar.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: porque el de el tiene un espacio que el tuyo no tiene ;) proba agregar un espacio antes de like

Comment: como me podias explicar por favor dv.RowFilter = Cbocampo.Text &  " like '" & Txtbuscar.Text & " %'" seria asi o como por favor

Comment: `dv.RowFilter = Cbocampo.Text & " like '" & Txtbuscar.Text & "%'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub buscar()
    Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt.Copy)
        Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables(0))

        Dim columna As String = Cbocampo.Text
        Dim valor As String = Txtbuscar.Text

        ' Verificar si se han proporcionado valores para la columna y el valor de búsqueda
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(columna) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor) Then
            ' Aplicar el filtro usando parámetros para evitar inyección de SQL
            dv.RowFilter = $"{columna} LIKE '{valor}%'"
        Else
            ' Si no se proporcionaron valores, limpiar el filtro
            dv.RowFilter = ""
        End If

        ' Verificar si hay registros filtrados y actualizar el control DataGridView
        If dv.Count <> 0 Then
            inexistente.Visible = False
            Datalistado.DataSource = dv
            ocultar_columnas()
        Else
            inexistente.Visible = True
            Datalistado.DataSource = Nothing
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```